# 2009 Honda Civic making noises as I accelerate

Tags: honda, noise, civic

I am currently driving a 2009 Honda Civic with about 125000 miles on it. I am noticing a noise coming from under the hood when I accelerate. The more I accelerate, the louder the noise gets that’s coming from the front and sounds like under the hood.

https://youtube.com/shorts/HbYPXtKFl5Y?si=0hVhB_9-LN0AX1WV

https://youtube.com/shorts/t_P2pcosCOg?si=ZbV2VGY1wPgds_pV

I’ve taken it to two different shops but they check it out and say it’s fine. I am just not sure what else to do or where to start to find out what the issue is.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!